Is teaching school kids chesed?
Is a teacher who teaches students (not Torah) considered as having done chesed, despite the fact that it’s their job and they’re being paid for it

למאי נפקא מינה...

@shmosel no practicality, purely philosophical

What's the philosophical נפק"מ?

@shmosel whether you get שכר

You can the same question in more general terms.  Is someone who is getting paid (going rate for such work)  EVER doing a chesed. See the first Sdei Chemed on Sukkah about if someone getting paid is considered an oisek b'mitzva who is pottur  from sukka
